# Can anyone tell me why I'm getting a 404 error in the console?

Tags: javascript

I'm making an api call to the rescountries api.
When I open up the console. I get the following error
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
However I seem to be getting an object printed out in the console that's coming from the restcountries api via the "console.log(data)" line.
Is it to do with the API itself or something I did in my code? Thanks in advance.

```
"use strict";

const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-country");
const countriesContainer = document.querySelector(".countries");

const getCountryData = function (country) {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`); 
  request.send();
request.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const [data] = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
    console.log(data);
    const html = `<article class="country">
    <img class="country__img" src="${data.flag}"/>
    <div class="country__data">
      <h3 class="country__name">${data.name}</h3>
      <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
      <p class="country__row"><span></span>${(
        +data.population / 100000
      ).toFixed(1)}</p>
      <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${data.languages.eng}</p>
      <p class="country__row"><span></span>${data.currencies.symbol}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  `;
    countriesContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
    countriesContainer.lastElementChild.opacity = 1;
  });
};


getCountryData("GB");
getCountryData("usa");
```

Comment: Go to the browser webtools `ctrl+shift+i` (pc) or `cmd+shif+i` (mac) , open the Network panel and click on the call that happened and try to understand from there why the URL is invalid, because 404 is the HTTP status "Not found" means you are trying to access an inexistent URL. Be sure to check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses .

Answer (score 1):

You have 404 error because you have following divs `<img class="country__img" src="">`
The `src` attribute should be an URL - not a symbol. You have 2 calls one for UK and one for USA so you will have 2 such images and 2 `404 Not found` errors will appear.

So your line of code where you produce this image i.e. `<img class="country__img" src="${data.flag}"/>` should be probably `<div>${data.flag}</div>` or similar.

Example:

```js
"use strict";

const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-country");
const countriesContainer = document.querySelector(".countries");

const getCountryData = function (country) {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`); 
  request.send();
request.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const [data] = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
    console.log(data);
    const html = `<article class="country">
    <div class="country__img">${data.flag}</div>
    <div class="country__data">
      <h3 class="country__name">${data.name}</h3>
      <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
      <p class="country__row"><span></span>${(
        +data.population / 100000
      ).toFixed(1)}</p>
      <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${data.languages.eng}</p>
      <p class="country__row"><span></span>${data.currencies.symbol}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  `;
    countriesContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
    countriesContainer.lastElementChild.opacity = 1;
  });
};


getCountryData("GB");
getCountryData("usa");
```

```html
<div class="countries"></div>
```

Comment: I would also guess that it is likely that what you mention is the problem. But `<img class="country__img" src=""> The src attribute should be an URL - not a symbol.` is a bit misleading. Having `` in the URL is not necessarily a problem, it is a Unicode character and would translate to `%F0%9F%87%BA%F0%9F%87%B8` in the URL, and a server could recognize that as `` and  return a `200` response for that request.

Comment: And this url exactly generates a 404 Not found when the browser tries to load the image ... I might not explained it well but it its logical ... of course you may set `src` attribute to any valid or invalid url even it is a unicode symbol but it will be casted and treated as url. Of course you may set it with base64 image data too, but that's not the case.